# Right path for live sass compiler?

Tags: html, css, sass

What is the right path if ever I already have style/css/main.css folder?
How can I map livesasscompile on the same folder? Because it will automatically map on my scss folder.

```
 "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [

            {
                "format": "expanded",
                "extensionName": ".css",
                "savePath": PATH
            }
        ],
        "liveSassCompile.settings.generateMap": true
    }
```

Comment: Brebber's answer is correct :) You can also remove the `"savePath"` if you're fine with the default folder. You don't need to write it.

Answer (score 0):

That are the settings I use ... maybe you like to try it:

```
// note: remove comments when use

    "settings": {

        // output: generate files to ...
        // null = same folder as Sass file
        "liveSassCompile.settings.formats":[
            {
                "format": "expanded",
                "extensionName": ".css",
                "savePath": null
            },

            // optional: add more SASS outputs ...

        ],

        "liveSassCompile.settings.generateMap": true,

    

    }  //settings
```